# Ubuntu Server 18.04 and OpenSSH 8.2 - when?

Tags: 18.04, ssh, openssh, 20.04

I need support for Yubikey's for a project. Sysops need to log on to an Ubuntu Server from remote positions using them. I see that openssh 8.2 has native support for it.

Will openssh 8.2 be available for Ubuntu Server in precompiled versions (I can do a compile myself - but others will do the support later on, so having on one of the standard repositories will be a great help) anytime soon?

Yours,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

There is good change that next LTS Ubuntu will get openssh 8.2 by default. Debian has it in the next main release the SID unstable route and therefore it's included the proposed channel if you install 20.04 LTS in your computer.

Comment: Nice to know! Thank you! Thats a partial solution. The problem is that we are setting up the first version of an upcoming system on 18.04.3 LTS within 2-3 months. We'll have to do a compile of OpenSSH 8.2p1, and tell our successors that it will be a standard feature later on.

Comment: So I installed a Focal Fossa - which at the moment is at OpenSSH 8.1p1 - one minor release away, and now await the coming of the next iteration with 8.2p1 ! It seems that the rest of my stuff works with Focal Fossa, and that gives a good feeling!

Comment: Is there any ongoing work to include the OpenSSH 8.2p1 instead of the OpenSSH 8.1p1?

Comment: Far I can known, it's available for everyone if you enabled Proposed-repository from Software and Update application. Exact version what is available currently is 8.2p1-4. Answer for your question is : Yes there is and everything what package maintainers can do has been done and now rest is relies on release manager(s).

Comment: I can confirm that openssh 8.2 is available in the Focal Fossa if you enable Proposed  repository from Developers options pane. Of course you get lots of changes after apt update and apt dist-upgrade process.

Comment: Thank you! Am trying to do that right now. I run the server version and don't have a Developers options pane. I do try to find a command line equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS will not get OpenSSH 8.2.  It will stay on version 7.6.

Ubuntu 20.04 does have OpenSSH 8.2 now.

OpenSSH 8.2 does include new support for FIDO U2F tokens, including the Yubikey.
Note that **both** the client and server must have OpenSSH 8.2 in order to work this way.

However, Yubikeys support many other methods to secure SSH authentication besides FIDO U2F.  Including PIV, PGP, and OTP methods, which support much older versions of OpenSSH.
See the [Yubikey documentation](https://developers.yubico.com/SSH/) for tips on implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

Needed this for Yubikey SSH keygen.  Got this to work, but only after installing libssl-dev and libkrb5-dev first.  Error fixed was "krb5.h: No such file or directory"